# Multiple Replace Statements in a single string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, sql-update, str-replace

a sample of it looks like this in my table with new line breaks and all. This is just one sample of the questions, I have about 15 of these groups of questions with different question/answers combos. All follow the same format `question: answer <new line break>`

```
Phone Number: 1234567890
School Name: UCLA
Major: Economics
Graduation Date: 06/2012
Birthday: 01/01/1990
```

I need to run some update statements to make this data look like this.

```
~Phone Number: 1234567890
~School Name: UCLA
~Major: Economics
~Graduation Date: 06/2012
~Birthday: 01/01/1990
```

Now this example has 5 lines. However there are fields with 10 lines of questions and answers.

Individually these are pretty strait forward replace statements and my sql looks like this.

```
select 
replace(notes, 'Phone Number: ', '~Phone Number: '),
replace(notes, 'School Name: ', '~School Name: '),
replace(notes, 'Major:', '~Major: '),
replace(notes, 'Graduation Date: ', '~Graduation Date: '),
replace(notes, 'Birthday: ', '~Birthday: ')
from notes 
where ...
```

I can run update statements piecemeal, but I would like to run one update statement and update each group (this is one group here) with one update statement.

Thank you

Comment: Hint: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5549/using-regular-expressions-to-manipulate-text-in-sql-server-management-studio-2017/

Comment: Quickest and easiest way would be to just nest the `replace` statements so you end up with 5 nested replaces. SQL Server doesn't support regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

This makes your query `non-sargeable`, but if performance is not of top concern, you could do

```
update my_table
set notes=concat('~',notes)
where left(notes,charindex(':',notes)-1) in ('Phone Number','School Name' and so on)
```

Comment: I would still have to list all the column names in the in portion of the code with this logic?

Comment: @YelizavetaYR Sorry I misread your comment earlier.  The values inside `in` are the values in your column that you want to clean up. The where clause filters for those groups where values in notes start with 'Phone Number', 'School Name' and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is adding a character (~) to the beginning of each line, could you replace line breaks with a line break plus '~'?

```
UPDATE [tablename]
  SET [columnname] = replace([columnname], 
                             CHAR(10), 
                             CONCAT(CHAR(10), 
                             '~'))
```

See: https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-carriage-return-or-tab-in-sql-server-string/
for more info on line breaks and carriage returns in SQL Server

Comment: Hello, the only issue is that there are paragraphs in some of the questions, those line breaks we want to avoid. We only want to update the line breaks with the actual questions in them.